# Is it a bad Idea to set state in a while loop?

Tags: reactjs, while-loop

Im having an issue with a while loop and set state. Basically I have a really simple bit of code that takes a random number and adds it a value stored in the state. But when I do something like this:

```
updateScore(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    this.setState({points: this.state.points + random});
    console.log(random);
}
```

and then call this function in a while loop

```
while(this.state.points < 20){
    updateScore()
}
```

I get an infinite loop of random numbers being logged in the console. 
If I change the while to if it works perfectly fine. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not a good idea to use set State with loops?

Comment: setState is not synchronous so the issue could be related to that.

Comment: Strictly from a methodology point of view, it seems that you are making your state hard to reason about by adding the while loop. Simplicity is King.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While loops are tricky and you can run into race conditions, especially with state changes.

I think this would be better:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.points < 20) {
        updateScore();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random` returns a value between 0 and 1. Therefore `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)` can never be greater than 20. This is the reason why you got infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

setState is used to trigger a rerender so React batches the invocations for a performance gain which I imagine is the issue you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your codes is, `setState` is asynchronous and could be executed in batch. Try to modify your code to:

```
updateScore(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {points: prevState.points + random}
    });
    console.log(random);
}
```